# What approach should I apply if I want to manipulate HTML/CSS without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do some html/css manipulation without the help of a large library such as jQuery.

I'm using [this code](https://github.com/ded/domready) to know when the dom is ready, and call my functions from within that:

```
domready(function () {
  functionOne();
})
```

How would I do changes to the DOM, e.g. remove/add classes to an element, and let it be aware of it such that I can do the following (on last line):

```
<div id="myElement" class="active"></div>  

var linkElement = document.getElementById("myElement");
linkElement.className.replace(" active", " unactive");
elementByClass = document.getElementsByClassName("unactive")[0];
```

Comment: You need to reassign the string to the `.className`.

Comment: If you're targeting modern browsers: `linkElement.classList.remove("actice"); linkElement.classList.add("unactive");` :-)

Comment: Here is all you need to know about the DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM

Comment: Well, you can do it with pure javascript (or any other script language you see fit, assuming you have control over client-side rendering...which is the only reason to avoid jQuery that I can think of).  The thing is, you'll end up writing more code and it'll likely be less optimized than jQ already is.

Comment: @MikeHometchko: If done right-minded, it will be more optimized than jQuery. jQuery also makes bad code patterns very easy.

Comment: @MikeHometchko It won't be less optimized if it doesn't contain tons of unused functionality.

Comment: I am aware of the shortcomings of jQuery...but it's not terrible.  What I meant is if he's a novice with JS, and the project demands optimization, he's likely better off with jQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your browser(s) supports [Array extras](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6) and [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList), do this:

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName('existingClass');
elements.forEach(function(elem){
    elem.classList.remove("existingClass");
    elem.classList.add("newClass");
    elem.classList.add("foo","bar");
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what browsers you want to support. The latest browsers already implement many jQuery features natively (querySelector, classlist, etc).

Your code is a good start but it doesn't work because replace doesn't change the string in place, it returns a new one.

```
<div id="myElement" class="active"></div>  

var linkElement = document.getElementById("myElement");
linkElement.className = linkElement.className.replace(" active", " unactive");
elementByClass = document.getElementsByClassName("unactive")[0];
```

Take a look at classList to check a much more robust implementation of working with classes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

Answer (score 0):

try this code to assign class name to your DOM element.

```
document.getElementById("myElement").className = "myClassName";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign the the DOM property that's it.

for example you can assign the classname property of DOM element as

```
document.getElementById("myElement").className = "myClassName";
```

You can use[Element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) for setting all other Dom elements attributes.